# How to minimise time in converting numpy ndarray to list

Tags: python, list

I want to take pixel values of image as a list  of tuple so I converted it `numpy` array to list but it is taking to much time to convert

```
import time
t1=time.time()    
import  cv2    
import  numpy  as  np 

img=cv2.imread("Desert.jpg")    
array=np.array(img)    
a=array.tolist()
t2=time.time()
print(t2-t1)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your aim is to only to convert the 'img' matrix into a vector that needn't explicitly be a list then you can just convert the ndarray to a single line vector as:

```
img=cv2.imread("Desert.jpg")
array=np.array(img) 
a = np.reshape(array,-1,1)
t2=time.time()
print(t2-t1)
```

[out]

```
0.016440153121948242
```

But if it is your intention to convert to a list then:

```
img=cv2.imread("Desert.jpg")
array=np.array(img) 
a = list(array)
t2=time.time()
print(t2-t1)
```

[out]

```
0.007548332214355469
```

Comment: Mark this as right answer to indicate the problem is solved